# How to retrive data from database to a treeview using laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-5.1

My requirement is to construct the treeview using database values.

Here are my database tables:

```
|    Categories   |  |sub_categories   |
|     id(pk)      |  |    id(pk)       |
|  cate_name      |  | sub_cat_name    |
| route_name      |  | route_name      |
                     |Categories_id(fk)|
```

I'm getting **categories** and **sub categories** as well which are related to categories table.

Here is my Controller code:

```
$treeView = DB::table('categories')
                ->join('sub_categories', 'sub_categories.categories_id', '=', 'categories.id')
                ->get();
```

Here is the HTML structure  in the *.blade.php :

```
@foreach($treeView as $tv)
                <li class="treeview">
                    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-link"></i> <span>{{ $tv->category_name }}</span> <i
                                class="fa fa-angle-left pull-right"></i></a>
                    <ul class="treeview-menu">
                        <li class=""><a href="#">{{$tv->sub_category_name}}</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Update Article</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            @endforeach
```

But it doesn't work fine. It gives same main category again and again..
Can anyone suggest a proper way to retrieve data?

Comment: Are you using eloquent? What are the model names?

Comment: no .. I'm not using eloquent... I'm using **Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB**.

Comment: I have my own database.. So I' not using Eloquent..

Comment: Well, it's not that you cannot have both ;) Please check back in half a day, I'll apot an answer when i am at the computer if noone answers by then

Comment: K.. Thanks.. I m looking forward to hear from u soon...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest you use Eloquent, as it will make the code simpler and will make your life easier in the future.

Create model classes for your tables:

```
class Category extends Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model {
  protected $table = 'Categories';

  public function subcategories() {
    return $this->hasMany(Subcategory::class, 'Categories_id');
  }
}

class Subcategory extends Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model {
  protected $table = 'sub_categories';

  public function category() {
    return $this->belongsTo(Category::class, 'Categories_id');
  }
}
```

In your controller fetch data like that:

```
$treeView = Category::with(['subcategories'])->get();
```

And then in the view:

```
@foreach($treeView as $category)
  <li class="treeview">
    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-link"></i> <span>{{ $category->cate_name }}</span> <i class="fa fa-angle-left pull-right"></i></a>
    <ul class="treeview-menu">
      @foreach($category->subcategories as $subcategory)
        <li class=""><a href="#">{{$subcategory->sub_category_name}}</a></li>
      @endforeach
    </ul>
  </li>
@endforeach
```

I can see that your categories and subcategories have the same stucture. You might consider storing them in the same table, just add a **parent_id** field to the table and set it to NULL for parent categories and to parent id for subcategories.

Comment: thanks for your quick reply.. I tried using your code example. But It gives me the error **BadMethodCallException in Builder.php line 2003: Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::all()**

Comment: I created **Category** and **Subcategory** classes in **app/** directory as u mentioned...

Comment: I wanted to check if the category has subcategories else do another work.. I tried it like below. But it didnt retrieve the required answer .. Is anything wrong with it ??

Comment: `@foreach($treeView as $category)
@if($category->has('subcategories'))
<li class="treeview">
<a href="#"><i class="fa fa-link"></i> <span>{{ $category->category_name }}</span>
 <i class="fa fa-angle-left pull-right"></i></a>
<ul class="treeview-menu">
                @foreach($category->subcategories as $subcategory) <li class=""><a href="#">{{$subcategory->sub_category_name}}</a></li>
@endforeach
     </ul> </li> @else
<li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-link"></i> <span>{{$category->category_name }}</span></a></li>
@endif  @endforeach`

Comment: Where did you get that has() idea? Anyway, see the answer in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31509536/get-categories-which-has-subcategories-using-laravel/31509660#31509660