# get categories which has subcategories using laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5

I'm retrieving data from two tables which are categories and subcategories.

categories `cat_id` contains inside the subcategories table as a foreign key.

Here is my code from Category model:

```
class Category extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'categories';

    public function subcategories()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Subcategory::class, 'categories_id');
    }
}
```

Here is my code from SubCategory model:

```
class Subcategory extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'sub_categories';

    public function category()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Category::class, 'categories_id');
    }
```

This is how I retrieve data from my controller:

```
$treeView = Category::with(['subcategories'])->get();
```

This is how my `.blade.php` part looks like:

```
@foreach($treeView as $category)
    @if($category->has('subcategories'))
        <li class="treeview">
            <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-link"></i> <span>{{ $category->category_name }}</span>
                <i class="fa fa-angle-left pull-right"></i></a>
            <ul class="treeview-menu">
                @foreach($category->subcategories as $subcategory)

                    <li class=""><a href="#">{{$subcategory->sub_category_name}}</a></li>

                @endforeach
            </ul>
        </li>
    @else
        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-link"></i> <span>{{ $category->category_name }}</span></a></li>
    @endif

@endforeach
```

As above html structure: I am going to construct a tree view if any category has sub categories else show the category without a tree view . But I get all the categories with or without subcategories inside a tree view.. Can anyone suggest a way please...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just wrap the nested ul in an if:

```
@if($category->subcategories->count())
  <ul class="treeview-menu">
    @foreach($category->subcategories as $subcategory)
      <li class=""><a href="#">{{$subcategory->sub_category_name}}</a></li>
    @endforeach
  </ul>
@endif
```