# List tree view using eloquent

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, tree, distinct

I have this table structure below

**TABLE VIEW**

```
+------+---------------+---------------+---------------+
|id    |  group_name   |   sub_group   |    title      |
+------+---------------+---------------+---------------+
|1     |  Mobile Phone |   Apple       |  Iphone X     |
|2     |  Mobile Phone |   Apple       |  Iphone 7 Plus|
|3     |  Mobile Phone |   Samsung     |  J6 Plus      |
|4     |  Mobile Phone |   Nokia       |  XpressMusic  |
+------+---------------+---------------+---------------+
```

How to loop this table and store in an array and look like this

**LOOP**

```
Mobile Phone
    -> Apple
        -> Iphone X
        -> Iphone 7 Plus
    -> Samsung
        -> J6 Plus
    -> Nokia
        -> XpressMusic
```

This is my code using eloquent, I've run a distinct under group_name sub_group but I have no idea how am I gonna get the title based on `group_name` and `sub_group`

```
$group_names = ThisIsModel::distinct()->orderBy('group_name', 'asc')->get(['group_name']);
```

I don't know what to do next. Please help me. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally you cannot have that easily without having 03 separates table and using eloquent relations like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31502207/3256489).

But for you case with single table, maybe this works ?

```
ThisIsModel::select(DB::raw("group_concat(distinct(group_name)) as group_name, group_concat(distinct(sub_group)) as sub_group, group_concat(title) as title"))->groupBy('sub_group', 'group_name')->get()->groupBy('group_name')->toArray();
```

which gives result as follow:

```
[
     "Mobile Phone" => [
       [
         "group_name" => "Mobile Phone",
         "sub_group" => "Apple",
         "title" => "Iphone X,Iphone 7 Plus",
       ],
       [
         "group_name" => "Mobile Phone",
         "sub_group" => "Nokia",
         "title" => "XpressMusic",
       ],
       [
         "group_name" => "Mobile Phone",
         "sub_group" => "Samsung",
         "title" => "J6 Plus",
       ],
     ],
   ]
```

To get the leaves on `title`, you just need to explode with `,` separator and you have all in one query.

Comment: I will try this one and let you know

Comment: I am confused with 'test' and 'DB' is that a model?

Comment: sorry about `test`, it should be your `ThisIsModel`. The `DB::raw( )` allows you to write raw sql in `select` with eloquent way

Comment: I got this error `Class 'App\Controllers\DB' not found`

Comment: You have to import it in the file `use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;`

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by using groupBy()

```
$group_names = Employee::query()
            ->orderBy('sub_group', 'asc')
            ->get()
            ->groupBy('group_name','sub_group');
```

Then you will have a collection on $group_names with key like Mobile phone and subgroups like apple, samsung etc.

Comment: so what it returned ? Is there any error or you are not getting expected array?